# Using MethodCall Expression to call Attribute.GetCustomAttributes

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I am trying to create a delegate with expressiontrees for reading custom attributes. The sample code is

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class TestAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}


 [TestAttribute(Description="sample text")]
 public class TestClass
 {
 }
```

I want to get Description property value with a Func delegate. I want to achive this with expressions which creates this delegate at runtime.So i tried to write something like

```
public  Func<T, string> CreateDelegate<T>()
    {
       //Below is the code which i want to write using expressions
        //TestAttribute attribute = typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestAttribute), false)[0];
        //return attribute.Description;

        ParameterExpression clazz = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T),"clazz");
        ParameterExpression description = Expression.Variable(typeof(string),"description");
        ParameterExpression attribute=Expression.Variable(typeof(TestAttribute),"attribute");

        MethodCallExpression getAttributesMethod = Expression.Call(typeof(Attribute).GetMethod("GetCustomAttributes"),clazz);

        Expression testAttribute = Expression.TypeAs(Expression.ArrayIndex(getAttributesMethod, Expression.Constant(0)), typeof(TestAttribute));
        BinaryExpression result = Expression.Assign(description, Expression.Property(testAttribute, "Description"));

        BlockExpression body = Expression.Block(new ParameterExpression[] { clazz, attribute,description },
            getAttributesMethod, testAttribute, result);             

        Func<T, string> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(body, clazz).Compile();
        return lambda;
    }
```

But when i call this method, i get an AmbiguousMatchException at getAttributesMethod line and it says "Ambiguous match found." So how can i use Attribute.GetCustomAttribute() method within expression tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
MethodCallExpression getAttributesMethod = Expression.Call(typeof(Attribute),
    "GetCustomAttributes", null, Expression.Constant(typeof(T)));
```

But why do you return a `Func<T, string>`? What do you use as the parameter in the delegate call?

Comment: this is a simplified version of actual method which uses reflection intensively. I return a delegate here to get rid of reflection based drawbacks. I often use some helper classes with custom attributes as the parameter in the delegate call. With your changes the code above works just fine.Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually this block of Reflection here:

```
typeof(Attribute).GetMethod("GetCustomAttributes")
```

`GetMethod` will throw that exception if there are overloads of it and you don't specify the parameter types.

Try:

```
typeof(Attribute).GetMethod("GetCustomAttributes", new [] {typeof(MemberInfo)})
```

Comment: this time exception changed to ArgumentException. Pufff i stuck really.

Comment: @OlcaySeker Can you replace the `blah blah` in your question so that I can run the code?